# Different buffer distance left and right form line?

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I'm trying to make different buffer zones, left and right from the line. I made processing model (picture). I can do this with this module, but I can not specify the value that I want. I am executing only the default value in the model. Is there a possibility that, when starting the module, open the window to enter the value,  left and right? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add two 'String' inputs, one for left and one for right buffers. These will be converted to numbers for use in the buffer algorithm - in the options for each 'Single sided buffer', select the names of the string parameters for the distance:

[image]

[image]